Clone tool in gimp not working properly only a small area is reproduced even with a large brush
Clone tool in gimp not working properly, only a small area is reproduced even with a large brush

Please provide a screenshot of the Gimp UI, showing layers and tool options.

Guess 1: Your layer is so small that the clone doesn't fit. GIMP allows smaller layers than the image size. Expanding image dimensions doesn't make the layers bigger automatically.
An example:

In the left I have a bitmap image of letter a. In the right I have an attempt to make a copy of it by using the clone brush. The cloning stops to the layer border, The layer border is the yellow dashed line.
You can make the layer borders visible by checking option View > Show layer border. You can expand a layer to the image size by applying Layer > Layer to image size. Before doing it select the right layer in the Layers panel.
The image resizing dialog Image > Canvas size has option to change also layer sizes. It must be selected manually, it's not ON by default.
Guess 2: You have a multilayer image, Clone brush copies only material from one layer at a time. Or there's a layer mask which makes a part of the target layer invisible.
You did not give any layer info, so it's possible that you still haven't fully understood its importance. Make possible  to get a proper answer instead of guesses. Include the screenshot of the image, the result of the cloning attempt and the layers panel content.
